# Javascript Fetch use status code more than one time

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I need to find a way when the request gets a 403 I can use `if` before calling JSON with status and data. Only 403 returns HTML

```js
const response = await fetch(
  // Fetch info
).then((response) => {
  if (!response.ok && response.status === 403) {
    // Stuffs
    throw new Error('Exception message'); // Raise error to stop the code
  }

  return response.json();
})
.then((data) => ({
  // I need use status code again, and keep the if statement 403 on top.
  status: response.status, 
  data,
}));
```

Comment: try { const response = await fetch(".."); console.log(response.status); if(response.ok) return response.json(); } catch(err) { /* do ur error logic here */}

Comment: Don't mix `await` and `then` syntax, they do not fail gracefully when used together.

Comment: @Jeremy "*hey do not fail gracefully when used together.*" what does that even mean? Rejecting from the promise chain will still raise an exception from the `await`. As usual.

Comment: @VLAZ Amongst other things, Promises uses `.then/.catch/.finally` for error handling whilst `await` uses `try catch` to deal with error handling. Jeremy is completely correct with this statement. How would one surface an error thrown within a `.then/.catch` clause to an outer scoped `try catch` ?

Comment: @Joel The way you use `try`/`catch` with `await` *requires* the promise to be rejected. `try { await f() }  catch (e) {}` will go in the `catch` block if the promise from `f()` rejects. There are no multiple error mechanism - it's just one. Based on the state of the promise. An `await` either continues on fulfilled promise or raises an exception which goes to the `catch` block of a `try`/`catch` block. The `catch` block is mirrored by a `.catch()` handler. The semantics of the promise API follow the `try`/`catch` for maximum comaptibility https://jsbin.com/jalahijuqa/1/edit

Comment: @VLAZ have a read here https://dev.to/maximization/why-you-shouldnt-mix-promisethen-with-asyncawait-syntax-gl1 TLDR `promises have a different error handling mechanism than async/await`.

Comment: @Jeremy an article from somebody who obviously doesn't understand promises? Thanks, I don't really need it. I only had to scroll to this example: https://i.imgur.com/Bgkq1YV.png the correct answer is *neither*. Not really. The *correct code* would be to use `await Promise.update()` which will then do A. The B happens because you have *not* used `await` nor handled the rejection with `Promise.update().catch()`. That's really it. It's not a mystery. Nor is it some spooky extra mechanism. Essentially imagine there was a `Promise.reject("boom")` instead - it's very obviously not handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep with the `.then()` style you have rather than switch to only using `await`, you can just move the 2nd `.then()` to where you have `response` in scope:

```
const result = await fetch(...).then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok && response.status === 403) {
        throw new Error('Exception message');
    }    
    return response.json().then(data => {
        status: response.status,
        data
    });
});
```

Or, you can just use `await` and avoid the mixing of `await` and `.then()` which is generally less clear and should usually be avoided:

```
const response = await fetch(...);
if (!response.ok && response.status === 403) {
    throw new Error('Exception message');
}
const data = await response.json();
const result = {status: response.status, data};
```

Note, I've avoided using `response` in two separate places to mean two different things and used `result` for the final result and left `response` as the `fetch()` response.

Comment: Don't mix `async/await` with `.then/.catch` unless you have a VERY good reason. In this case, you don't.

Comment: @Joel this advice is to avoid confusion. There is no real reason to avoid it other than that. And this code does not seem confusing.

Comment: @Joel - I've already offered another option that doesn't mix them.  The mixing came from the OP's question so I was just showing them how to adapt what they had.

Comment: @VLAZ There's a big difference between the two. Promise is an object representing intermediate state of operation which is guaranteed to complete its execution at some point in future. Async/Await is a syntactic sugar for promises, a wrapper making the code execute more synchronously. i.e. await the response. Promise has 3 states – resolved, rejected and pending. Async await doesn't have any states. It returns a promise, either resolved or rejected. `promise.then(fn)` continues execution whilst `await` awaits. Error handling is `.then() and .catch() ` and for async `try catch`. I could go on

Comment: @Joel you're not describing any differences that matter. `x = await f();` is the same as `f().then(x => {})`. Mixing the two concept is not only *possible* it's literally the only way the code works if you ever use `await`. There are cases where you probably don't want to mix the two - when reading the code will be more confusing than needed. But just saying "they are different because they use different syntax" is missing the forest for the trees.

Comment: @VLAZ  *"`x = await f();` is the same as `f().then(x => {})`"* No, it's not the same. Check here for a simple demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ljkrwn?file=index.js

Comment: @Joel are you trying to deliberately twist my words? https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mfbfvw?file=index.js You *should* know that `await` is built on top of promises. You already said so with "Async/Await is a syntactic sugar for promises" and then suddenly give me what should pass as proof two do not work the same, yet you're using code that just doesn't try *even try* to do the same things. What are you trying to argue here ultimately? There is no incompatibility between async/await and promise API.

Comment: Loving the friendly discussion guys. Here is why you should not mix them https://dev.to/maximization/why-you-shouldnt-mix-promisethen-with-asyncawait-syntax-gl1

Answer (score 1):

`response` is an argument to your first callback, it's not in scope in the second.

It will be a lot easier if you stop using `then` (in general, there is hardly ever a good reason to mix `async`/`await` and `then`):

```js
const response = await fetch(/* fetch info */)
if (!response.ok && response.status === 403) {
  // Stuffs
  throw new Error('Exception message') // Raise error to stop the code
}
const data = await response.json()
const result = {
  status: response.status, 
  data
}
```

Comment: I did not. You edited yours and verbatim copied mine.

Comment: I did not copy yours.

Comment: See, so we just had the same (obvious) solution and were simultaneously typing it up :)

Comment: ...and if you don't believe me, you can check the timestamps. [I answered at 07:57:18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maMO9.png) and [you added the solution in an edit to your answer at 07:58:19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUfT0.png), one minute and one second later.

Comment: It's...a very trivial and straight-forward transformation to go from promises to just `await` syntax. You end up with basically the same code. And the variable names are completely generic and *very* common for these use cases. So, I don't really think it was copied.